# Find the characteristic & minimal polynomials, eigenvectors, and dimension of the eigenspace for this 6x6 jordan matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

```
3 1 0 0 0 0 
0 3 1 0 0 0 
0 0 3 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1
```

I think the characteristic polynomial is: ((x-3)^3)((x-1)^3) Found by taking the number of each eigenvalue along the diagonal, 3 3's, 3 1's I think the minimal polynomial is: ((x-3)^3)((x-1)^2) Found by taking each eigenvalue, start with an exponent 1 and add 1 for the maximum number of 1's in a row along that eigenvalue's subdiagonal. Since there's 2 1's in a row for eigenvalue 3 we have 2+1=3 for an exponent, since there's only 1 1's in a row for the subdiagonal of eigenvalue 1, (x-1) has 2 for an exponent. Am I thinking about this correctly?How do I quickly find the eigenvectors and dimension? Thanks.

Comment: It would appear, from your deleted "answer", that you have figured out how to solve the problem. If that is the case, I would like to encourage you to write up your solution, and to post it as an answer. You might also consider "accepting" my answer by clicking in the check mark next to it, if you found my answer helpful.

Comment: Are you still here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the polynomials right. The eigenvectors are obvious --- no, really --- $(1,0,0,0,0,0)$ is an eigenvector for the eigenvalue 3, and both $(0,0,0,1,0,0)$ and $(0,0,0,0,0,1)$ are eigenvectors for the eigenvalue 1.

But, perhaps you also want the *generalized* eigenvectors?